# Selenium : Unable to Retrieve WebElements Stored in Map

Tags: java, selenium, collections, hashmap, testng

Defined  a number of **WebElements** using **@FindBy** Annotation

```
@FindBy(id="Corporate Insiders")
  private static WebElement FS_LvFd_Filers_CorporateInsidersLink;

  @FindBy(id="Companies")
  private static WebElement FS_LvFd_Filers_CompaniesLink;
```

Stored these WebElements in a **Map**

```
private static Map<String, WebElement> FilersClickWebElemnt = new HashMap<String, WebElement>(); 
FilersClickWebElemnt.put(prop.getString("F_CorporateInsiders"),FS_LvFd_Filers_CorporateInsidersLink);
FilersClickWebElemnt.put(prop.getString("F_Companies"),FS_LvFd_Filers_CompaniesLink);
```

Able to Successfully Store all the WebElements into the map by checking the size of Map....

> But Unable to perform actions **.click()** or **.getText()** on the
>   WebElements which are Retrieved form the Map FilersClickWebElemnt.

```
FilersClickWebElemnt.get(Sec_Filers).click();
FilersClickWebElemnt.get(Filers).click();
System.out.println(FilersClickWebElemnt.get(Filers).getText());
```

Even Tried doing this:

```
 WebElement e = FilersClickWebElemnt.get(Filers); 
                  e.click()
```

Where Sec_Filers and Filers are the Key to the Value Stored as WebElements in Map, passed as Arguments to this Function

Using: 
Selenium-server-standalone- 2.53.0,
Java 1.7,
FireFox Version 48.0(Gecko Driver),
Ubuntu 14.04,
Along with TestNG

Executing the Above actions/code does'nt give any Error in Eclipse Console.

Any one,
 please suggest me what could be wrong or is there any better approach.

Comment: Could you let us know why are you storing both elements into `Map`??

Comment: @SaurabhGaur: Trying to pick the Respective WebELement  in this common function which matches the Argument passed i.e Key and perform some actions on the selected WebElement. This Function is used by a lot of TC's to perform common operation on the Stored WebElements. Basically to reduce code lines.

Comment: But if you're storing elements for further process this wouldn't be available for long time due to stale of the element if page become change, so I don't think you're logic is good.

Comment: I would suggest try to find element when you've required for particular element instead of storing it.

Comment: @SaurabhGaur: I am just storing this WebElements onto the map for reuse for only certain test case. These TC's are like 1:many combination. Around 30 Tc's have same logic where Filers & Sec_Filers will be clicked and the result shall be asserted.. So WebElements are chosen differently for each TC's according to the Key passed as Filers & Sec_Filers.. If not using map then i need to write 30 Different Functions in the POM Page.  Some suggested to try For loop but the Iteration of 2 loops i & j will nearly take 28 cycles every time which adds to more execution time.

Comment: @SaurabhGaur: Its like Filers are First Menu Items And Sec_Filers are Sub Menu which are common for all the Entries of the Filers Menu. Only Thing is both of them Works as Combination like: 1:20, 2:20,etc. Results needs to extracted on the Dynamicaly generated grid and Assert the Tc's. Need to Separtely Code TC's for Each Combination. So used Map to Store WebElements and tried to choose the Respective element according to TC. Asserting the Combination result is same General Function for All. Stale Exception wont occur as these list of WebELemnts wont change in any future Build.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the information you provided, I am assuming, that you are storing the web element reference but not actual web element object, that is, you have to put the web element objects in map only after PageFactory.initElements(driver, class); gets called

So, I suggest you to add the web elements into map after initialization happens to elements

Comment: Let me know if that doesn't work or if it is not clear to you

Comment: No Actually the PageFactory.initElements(driver, class) gets initialized in the constructor of the Class. So when evr i create a object of this POM class page it gets Executed. Then In Another Function these addition of WebElements is coded which is called upon by the Object of the POM Class created.

Comment: Hey, let me put what I understood from your reply, 
1) You have declared web elements
2) You have constructor, where initialization is taking place on POM class
3) On the created object, you are calling a method to add these element, 

If this is what happening, 

as a quick suggestion, remove the static from the web elements declaration and try..

Comment: No tried with your Suggestion but it does not have any impact on the expected result. @FayazMd

Comment: Alright, since you are storing web elements in map, the order is not guarantee. In such case, are you getting a text object (webelement) from map and trying to click on it or may be trying to call .getText() on an object that doesn't have any text, will you confirm that are the corresponding objects retrieving from the map based on the key.?

Comment: i m unable to get any webElement according to the key used to fetch the webElement. I am able to successfully store the Ref Variabels i.e WebElements into the map but unable to retrieve them. Once upon successful retrieval only i can call either .getText() or .click() method Right?? But i am getting the Null Value when debugged in Eclipse....